# Python-Pandas JSON.normalize on non-Array JSON keys

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following JSON from a string and read it via `json.load`.
I would like to normalize its contents into a pandas data frame. But instead of creating a column for each "node" in the JSON graph, I want it to create a row for each depth=1 node

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.json_normalize({'a': {'i': 1, 'm': 'msg'}, 'b': {'i': 5, 'm': 'msg2'}} )
```

Output:

```
   a.i  a.m b.i b.m
0   1   msg 5   msg2
```

I want this instead:

```
    i   m
a   1   msg 
b   5   msg2
```

Do you know how to achieve that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `orient='index'` parameter

```
data = {'a': {'i': 1, 'm': 'msg'}, 'b': {'i': 5, 'm': 'msg2'}}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=data, orient='index')
```

Output

```
   i     m
a  1   msg
b  5  msg2
```

Comment: You're a saint! Thank You!